# Enterprise geodatabase on PostgreSQL backup and restore

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

windows 7, PostgreSQL 9.4/ArcSDE/PostGIS backend database that I  am transferring to another computer.

My backup command is as follows. host 5433

```
pg_dumpall -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -c -f "file.backup"
```

backups up all nice and everything.

when I go to restore it on windows 10, PostgreSQL 9.4, port 5433 I run

```
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -f file.backup
```

so everything restores okay. All tables, schemas, logins are good. I can connect with QGIS and everything works fine.

**Problem**

When I go to add an ArcGIS database connection I get this error

[image]

**UPDATE**

I uninstalled postgres on the new computer reinstalled 9.5, 
ran  `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f file.backup` on port 5432 and in the CMD I found 1 error it should while it is running the restore

```
psql:R:/Data/LUCZ_2017/blah.backup:12531010: ERROR:  relation "gdb_items" does not exist
```

whats going on here!

Based on Evan Carroll's suggestion I ran

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin>psql \duS+
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rizagha"
```

the CMD wouldn't let me enter my password, I pressed enter and received the above error

Comment: 5433 is not a valid instance. The proper syntax is hostname,5433. Please remember to include the entire error message ***as text*** in the body of your question.

Comment: 5433 works as a proper instance for me on my old computer. and even with localhost,5433 I get the exact same error

Comment: Did you change the database name? Does the table "lucz.sde.gdb_release" exist?

Comment: I did not change the database name, and the table "lucz.sde.gdb_release" does not even exists in my old working database

Comment: Are you sure you're restoring to port 5433 on Windows, 5432 is the default? Also you're connecting with user:conflict and restoring from user:postgres can you connect with user:postgres?

Comment: yes restoring on port 5433, the above commands are what I did

Comment: Maybe it's an ODBC driver problem? https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

Comment: @ziggy paste the result of `\duS+`

Comment: @EvanCarroll what is that

Comment: a command you can run in psql that shows the roles.

Comment: Can you connect to the server with the `conflict` user?

Comment: No, first you connect to the databsae, then you run it. or use`psql -d lucz -U conflict -c '\duS+'` note you still have to connect to the right database with the right username and password.

Answer (score 0):

### Can you connect with the `conflict` user using psql?

I'm guessing strongly that you don't have your `pg_hba.conf` configured properly. Check out the difference between the old install and the new install. It's not backed up with restore/dump. I assume you're missing something like this

```
host lucz conflict all md5
```

You need to at lest enable host to connect with md5.

See this guide on ["PostgreSQL is installed on a Windows server on ESRI" for more information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/configure-postgresql-accept-connections.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1ED2D1B12F454340B6A37F939E43D714).

### If you can connect

You may need the ESRI schema, `sde` which provides the `GDB_Release` table. ESRI provide either

1. A python script and a DLL
2. The [Create Enterprise Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-enterprise-geodatabase.htm) tool

You'll have to run one of those to turn your PostgreSQL into a geodatabase.

Comment: I cannot connect with the conflict user using psql

Comment: I'm contemplating uninstalling postgresql on this computer, reinstalling a newer version and trying to restore this

Comment: this did nothing host conflict all all md5 and conflict is a schema and login role not a database for me

Comment: @ziggy sorry I typeoed that pg_hba wrong, try that. and paste the result of `\duS+` as requested previously.

Comment: look at my update, once it fully restores I will go through your suggestions once more